# HTTP subtitles in WinJS video element

Tags: video, windows-runtime, html5-video, winjs

In the [HTML media playback sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Playback-Sample-3bdbe7c9) there's a code that demonstrates how to add subtitles to the video:

```
    <video id="subtitleVideo" style="position: relative; z-index: auto; width: 50%;"
        src="http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Videos/BehindIE9AllAroundFast/Video.mp4"
        poster="images/Win8MediaLogo.png" loop controls>
        <track id="scenario3entrack" src="media/sample-subtitle-en.vtt" kind="subtitles"
            srclang="en" default>
    </video>
```

It works fine, but when I change subtitle track src to `src="http://gilevskaya.com/subs.vtt"`, subtitles stop working.

The file being served is the same, why doesn't it work and how to fix it?

Comment: It could be an issue with cross-domain requests within the app container and the sandbox http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441129.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recreated the issue on my own domain. At first the subtitles didn't show. I noticed an error in the JavaScript Console in Visual Studio.

> MEDIA12604: Text Track: Unknown MIME type. hr=8007000b

So I added the mime type. My site runs on Apache. I added this line to the `.htaccess` file:

> AddType text/vtt;charset=utf-8 .vtt

This sets the `.vtt` type to be `text/vtt` and set the encoding to `utf-8`.

I'm sure it's not hard to find the ways of adding mime types for other servers.

I'm my case I had to add the "www" to the url too... But I think this has something to do with the way the server is set up.  You might not need this.